# Background of parent leaking when child's border radius is the same

Tags: html, css

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: steelblue;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

body {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

You can see that the white background of the parent is leaking behind the child, even though they have the same border-radius. How can I prevent this?

**Edit**: Neither of the duplicate questions appropriately answer my question. The leak still happens in the first question. The second question's marked answer uses an image and Javascript, which should not be necessary to fix this.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485207/border-radius-on-two-overlapping-elements-background-shines-through?rq=1 helps?

Comment: @ggorlen The accepted answer for that question uses javascript, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Cras that restriction might be worth mentioning in the post (although you did not tag JS, some folks might offer such a solution)

Comment: a better duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882283/pixelated-edge-around-a-css-circle-with-overflow-hidden

Comment: @dippas you may notice that we have no border and no padding so padding-box/content-box and border-box (the default one) are all the same and it won't correct the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the CSS to obtain a similar layout without this issue:

```css
#outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(to bottom,steelblue 50px,white 0);
  border-radius: 20px;
}


body {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
</div>
```

Comment: you learned gradients and thats your answer for everything?

Comment: @dippas yes exactly, you got it ;) I answer *only* with gradients ... by the way the duplicate question has nothing to do with this one ...

Comment: just 21% of your answers ;)

Comment: Surprisingly, this seems to be the best solution. All of the similar questions have utterly subpar answers. Thank you @TemaniAfif