# How to prevent background color of an image to show through at rounded corners?

Tags: html, css

I have an image element nested in a parent div. The parent has rounded corners and the image should adapt those. In case that the image doesn't load for some reason, a default background color should show. This is the general setup:

```css
.parent {
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="child" />
</div>
```

I would expect the image to fill the entire container and not let any red color from the background show through, however the corners look like this:

[image: thin line of red color visible at the rounded corners]

As you can see, there is a thin red line visible at the rounded corners. This happens in Chrome and Firefox. How do I get rid of that and make the image properly fill the corners?

Comment: Does [Background of parent leaking when child's border radius is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052113/background-of-parent-leaking-when-childs-border-radius-is-the-same) and the Q&As marked as duplicates help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No unfortunately, they're only using colors while I'm using images. I don't know what color the image will be at the corner.

Comment: Then my other suggestion would be to try various [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bummer. You could transform: scale(1.05) as a way around it. Or put the image in the background of the parent. : /

Comment: Why does upscaling the image hide the background when it's already large enough at default size? Is it a border rounding calculation error?

Comment: That's what I think. Over time, I've seen it behave differently - between different browsers / and little flukes here and there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am setting my image as a background-image to a div and had `background-repeat: no-repeat` which was the root cause. Removing this fixed it for me.